# calculate the average of each sublist separately inside a list of lists

Tags: python, list, average

I am really new to Python and I am trying to find average of a list of lists. 
I have a list of lists of float numbers that indicate the grades of courses per semester and looks like this:

```
 mylist =  [[[2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0], [2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0], [2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0], [2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0], [2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0], [2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0], [2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0], [2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0], [2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0], [2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0]], [[2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0], [2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0], [2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0], [2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0], [2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0], [2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0], [2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0], [2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0], [2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0], [2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0], [2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0], [2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0], [2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0], [2.67, 2.67, 2.0, 2.0]]]
```

What I want to do is find the average of each sublist and place it as a sublist again in order to access it easier. For example I want the following:

```
myaverage= [[[2.335],[2.335],[2.335],...]]]
```

It is not on purpose the same numbers it just happened at this part of the list that I am showing you. I tried to do this:

```
for s in mylist:  # for each list
        gpa = sum(s) / len(s)
        allGPA.append(gpa)
        for x in s:  # for each sublist
            x_ = x if type(x) is list else [x]
            myaverage.append(sum(x_) / float(len(x_)))
```

but I am getting this error:

> gpa = sum(s) / len(s) 
>   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

I cannot understand if my approach is completely wrong or if I am looping wrong through the list.

Comment: nitpick: instead of `if type(x) is list`, use `if isinstance(x, list)`

Comment: `mylist` is a list of lists of lists, so you need an extra loop there. Or, replace everything with `np.array(mylist).mean(axis=-1)`

Comment: you have 2 levels of sublists. you might be expecting  `print ([[sum(i)/len(i) for i in l] for l in mylist])`

Comment: @Marat this gives me an error from _method.py in _mean :  ret = ret / rcount and then again: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'

Comment: @piggy i have updated my answer and its as your expectations. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
from statistics import mean

avg = [[ mean(sub_list) for sub_list in list ] for list in mylist]
```

If the syntax looks a little confusing have a look at [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 1):

Check this out i have updated my answer, output is as it is you want.[image: **Output**]

```
allGPA = []
myaverage = mylist
c = 0
count = 0
gpa = [0]
for list in mylist:
    for i in range(len(list)):
        gpa[0] = sum(mylist[c][i]) / len(mylist[c][i])
        allGPA.append(gpa)
        myaverage[c][i] = gpa
        print(myaverage[c][i])

    c = c + 1
print(myaverage)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This gives me as a result a list and not a list with sublists as I needed.

Comment: No problem @piggy

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be prudent to hold your data in some sort of collection, lets use a dictionary and create a readable function to parse your data.

### Function

```
from collections import defaultdict

def return_averages(gpa_lists):
    """ Takes in a list of lists and returns a dictionary of averages.
     the key will be the level of each sublist."""
    gpa_dict = {number_of_list : outer_list for number_of_list, outer_list in enumerate(gpa_lists)}

    gpa_averages = defaultdict(list)
    
    for list_number,lists in gpa_dict.items():
        for each_list in lists:
            gpa_averages[list_number].append(sum(each_list) / len(each_list))
        
    return gpa_averages
```

### Usage.

```
return_averages(mylist)


defaultdict(list,
            {0: [2.335,
              2.335,
              2.335,
              2.335,
              2.335,
              2.335,
              2.335,
              2.335,
              2.335,
              2.335],
             1: [2.335,
              2.335,
              2.335,
              2.335,
              2.335,
              2.335,
              2.335,
              2.335,
              2.335,
              2.335,
              2.335,
              2.335,
              2.335,
              2.335]})
```